# Unable to ssh to remote server using paramiko module

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to ssh to a remote server using python paramiko module. I need to include the key file dynamically. My code is given below.

```
import getpass
import paramiko

server = raw_input("What is the server name? ")
username = raw_input("Enter the username: ")
passphrase = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter your passphrase: ")
key = '/home/%s/.ssh/id_rsa' % username

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=passphrase, key_filename=key)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('df -h')
print stdout.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

I am able to work with the code if I provide the key path directly instead of using the variable.

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 237, in connect
    for (family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr) in socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`enter code here`
```

Comment: Give us more details. What are you expecting to happen, and what's happening instead?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: >>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=passphrase, key_filename=key)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 237, in connect
    for (family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr) in socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
When I specify keyfile manually instead of a variable it works.

Comment: I am able to work with this code, If I specify the key_filename directly instead of using a variable(key).

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have some dns error here, Pasting my script to get ssh status over here, that is dealing all the exceptions (at least I have noted so far)

```
#!/bin/python3
import threading, time, paramiko, socket, getpass
from queue import Queue
locke1 = threading.Lock()
q = Queue()

#Check the login
def check_hostname(host_name, pw_r):
    with locke1:
        print ("Checking hostname :"+str(host_name)+" with " + threading.current_thread().name)
        file_output = open('output_file','a')
        file_success = open('success_file','a')
        file_failed = open('failed_file','a')
        file_error = open('error_file','a')
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        try:
          ssh.connect(host_name, username='root', password=pw_r, timeout=5)
          #print ("Success")
          file_success.write(str(host_name+"\n"))
          file_success.close()
          file_output.write("success: "+str(host_name+"\n"))
          file_output.close()

          # printing output if required from remote machine
          #stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("hostname&&uptime")
          #for line in stdout.readlines():
           # print (line.strip())

        except paramiko.SSHException:
                # print ("error")
                file_failed.write(str(host_name+"\n"))
                file_failed.close()
                file_output.write("failed: "+str(host_name+"\n"))
                file_output.close()
                #quit()
        except paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError:
                #print ("might be windows------------")
                file_output.write("failed: " + str(host_name + "\n"))
                file_output.close()
                file_failed.write(str(host_name+"\n"))
                file_failed.close()
                #quit()
        except socket.gaierror:
          #print ("wrong hostname/dns************")
          file_output.write("error: "+str(host_name+"\n"))
          file_output.close()
          file_error.write(str(host_name + "\n"))
          file_error.close()

        except socket.timeout:
           #print ("No Ping %%%%%%%%%%%%")
           file_output.write("error: "+str(host_name+"\n"))
           file_output.close()
           file_error.write(str(host_name + "\n"))
           file_error.close()

        ssh.close()


def performer1():
    while True:
        hostname_value = q.get()
        check_hostname(hostname_value,pw_sent)
        q.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print ("This script checks all the hostnames in the input_file with your standard password and write the outputs in below files: \n1.file_output\n2.file_success \n3.file_failed \n4.file_error \n")

    f = open('output_file', 'w')
    f.write("-------Output of all hosts-------\n")
    f.close()
    f = open('success_file', 'w')
    f.write("-------Success hosts-------\n")
    f.close()
    f = open('failed_file', 'w')
    f.write("-------Failed hosts-------\n")
    f.close()
    f = open('error_file', 'w')
    f.write("-------Hosts with error-------\n")
    f.close()

    with open("input_file") as f:
        hostname1 = f.read().splitlines()

#Read the standard password from the user
    pw_sent=getpass.getpass("Enter the Password:")
    start_time1 = time.time()

    for i in hostname1:
        q.put(i)
    #print ("all the hostname : "+str(list(q.queue)))
    for no_of_threads in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=performer1)
        t.daemon=True
        t.start()

    q.join()
    print ("Check output files for results")
    print ("completed task in" + str(time.time()-start_time1) + "seconds")
```